# android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #58: Error inflating class TextView

Tags: android, android-fragments, adapter

Hello i am getting following exception while setting data into adapter. please help me find out what i am doing wrong.

```
public class FeedWallAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private List<Entry> feedEntries;
    private Context mContext;

    public FeedWallAdapter(Context context, List<Entry> feedWallEntry) {

        this.mContext = context;
        this.feedEntries = feedWallEntry;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return feedEntries.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return feedEntries.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        ViewHolder holder;
        if (convertView == null) {

            LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater)
                    mContext.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.feed_wall_item, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.feed_title = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.feed_title);
            holder.feed_detail = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.feed_detail);
            holder.total_comments = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.total_comments);
            holder.date_text = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.date_text);
            holder.time_text = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.time_text);

            holder.mark_as_favourite = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.mark_as_favourite);
            holder.share_feed = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.share_feed);
            holder.post_no_of_comments = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.post_no_of_comments);
            holder.feed_image = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.feed_image);
            convertView.setTag(holder);

        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        holder.feed_title.setText(feedEntries.get(position).getTitle());
        holder.feed_detail.setText(feedEntries.get(position).getText());
        holder.total_comments.setText("" + feedEntries.get(position).getNumOfComments());
        holder.date_text.setText(feedEntries.get(position).getCreateAt());
        holder.time_text.setText(feedEntries.get(position).getCreateAt());

        if (feedEntries.get(position).getInFavorites().equals("false")) {

        } else {

        }

        return convertView;
    }

    class ViewHolder {
        TextView feed_title;
        TextView feed_detail;
        TextView total_comments;
        TextView date_text;
        TextView time_text;
        ImageView mark_as_favourite, share_feed, post_no_of_comments, feed_image;
    }

}
```

and here is the error that i am getting while adding data to my adapter.

```
01-06 15:33:50.869 6216-6216/com.pilot E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                         android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #58: Error inflating class TextView
                                                             at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
                                                             at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746)
                                                             at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:749)
                                                             at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:749)
                                                             at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:749)
                                                             at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
                                                             at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
                                                             at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
                                                             at com.pilot.adapter.FeedWallAdapter.getView(FeedWallAdapter.java:54)
                                                             at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2159)
                                                             at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1831)
                                                             at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:674)
                                                             at android.widget.ListView.fillFromTop(ListView.java:735)
                                                             at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1652)
                                                             at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:1994)
                                                             at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14015)
                                                             at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4373)
                                                             at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:1021)
                                                             at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14015)
                                                             at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4373)
                                                             at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
                                                             at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14015)
                                                             at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4373)
                                                             at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.onLayout(DrawerLayout.java:1043)
                                                             at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14015)
                                                             at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4373)
                                                             at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
                                                             at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14015)
                                                             at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4373)
                                                             at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1663)
                                                             at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1521)
                                                             at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1434)
                                                             at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14015)
                                                             at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4373)
                                                             at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
                                                             at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14015)
                                                             at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4373)
                                                             at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1663)
                                                             at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1521)
                                                             at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1434)
                                                             at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14015)
                                                             at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4373)
                                                             at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
                                                             at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14015)
                                                             at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4373)
                                                             at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:1892)
                                                             at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1711)
                                                             at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:989)
                                                             at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:4351)
                                                             at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:749)
                                                             at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:562)
                                                             at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:532)
                                                             at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:735)
                                                             at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
                                                             at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
                                                             at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5227)
                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:795)
                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:562)
                                                             at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
                                                          Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=6; index=7
                                                             at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:3628)
                                                            at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java
```

this how i am adding data to my adapter

```
mFeedWallAdapter = new FeedWallAdapter(getActivity(), mFeedWallArray);
mLogsListView.setAdapter(mFeedWallAdapter);
```

and here is my feed_wall_item.xml file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="250dp"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/hundred_ninety_dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/feed_layout"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginEnd="-30dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="-30dp"
            android:layout_weight=".9"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="2">

            <com.pilot.helper.RoundedImageView
                android:id="@+id/feed_image"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="150dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_margin="@dimen/five_dp"
                android:layout_weight=".75"
                android:paddingEnd="@dimen/five_dp"
                android:paddingStart="@dimen/five_dp"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:src="@drawable/bg_city"
                app:sriv_left_bottom_corner_radius="48dip"
                app:sriv_left_top_corner_radius="16dip"
                app:sriv_right_bottom_corner_radius="16dip"
                app:sriv_right_top_corner_radius="0dip" />

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1.25">


                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/feed_title"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/ten_dp"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:padding="10dp"
                    android:text="Feed title"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/black" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/feed_detail"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/feed_title"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/ten_dp"
                    android:padding="@dimen/five_dp"
                    android:text="hcsdcbsjsjkcsksbkdjs sdfdfv sdcsd  dfdf dfdf df dfgd gfdgdfgd dg fdgdfg dg dfgd gdg d fd df dfddgfgfd d dfgdf dfg d d df d dfvjksdkjsvj /n sdcsk  dhsdf s fsd fsod fos fos  fs fsd fosd of"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                    android:textDirection="firstStrongRtl" />
            </RelativeLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/post_type_camera_bg" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/main_bg_color"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/mark_as_favourite"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/five_dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/five_dp"
            android:padding="@dimen/ten_dp"
            android:src="@drawable/star" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/share_feed"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/five_dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/five_dp"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/mark_as_favourite"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/mark_as_favourite"
            android:padding="@dimen/ten_dp"
            android:src="@drawable/arrow" />


        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/five_dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/five_dp"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/share_feed"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/save_location"
            android:padding="@dimen/ten_dp">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/post_no_of_comments"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:src="@drawable/comment" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/total_comments"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:padding="@dimen/ten_dp"
                android:text="10"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/date_text"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="02 monday 2016"
                android:textColor="@color/white" />

            <View
                android:layout_width="@dimen/one_dp"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/fifteen_dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_margin="@dimen/five_dp"
                android:background="@color/white"
                android:gravity="center" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/time_text"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="1:00 AM"
                android:textColor="@color/white" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: which line is FeedWallAdapter.java 54 ?

Comment: convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.feed_wall_item, null); @Blackbelt

Comment: what are the values of `ten_dp`, `five_dp` and `@color/white` ?

Comment: @ankitaggarwal you are wrong. Have a look [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#attr_android:textDirection)

Comment: ten_dp = 10dp, five_dp = 5dp and color white is = #ffffff